# Is it safe to compile programs using cryptography with -Ofast?

Tags: c, gcc, cryptography

I'm building a toy cracking program for self teaching purposes in C. I want the brute forcing to run as fast as possible, and one of the considerations there is naturally compiler optimizations. Presumably, cryptographic implementations would break or have their results thrown off by forgoing floating point precision, but I tested enabling `-Ofast` (on gcc) with my current script and the final hash output from a long series of cryptographic functions remains the same as with just `-O3`.

I understand though that this isn't necessarily conclusive as there's a lot that can be going on under the hood with modern compilers, so my question is, will enabling `-Ofast` on my crypto cracking script potentially throw off the results of my crypto functions?

Comment: Which cryptographic algorithms depend on floating point?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Rot13.5 :-)

Comment: @SteveFriedl Pretty fixed if you ask me :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know the specifics of the internals of say AES or SHA. Is it pure integer operations?

Comment: It is supposed to be, yes. If it is not then it is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Ofast` does this:

> Disregard strict standards compliance.  -Ofast enables all -O3
>   optimizations.  It also enables optimizations that are not valid for
>   all standard-compliant programs.  It turns on -ffast-math and the
>   Fortran-specific -fstack-arrays, unless -fmax-stack-var-size is
>   specified, and -fno-protect-parens.

`-ffast-math` turns on a bunch of other flags, but none of them matter unless you're using floating-point arithmetic, which no hash function I'm aware of does.

`-fstack-arrays` and `-fno-protect-parens` don't do anything at all unless you're using Fortran.

Comment: In short, `-Ofast` does nothing unless it breaks your program, so there's no point in using it even if it is safe.